# Validating user is still authenticated in Azure AD using IdentityServer4/Azure AD SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, identityserver4

We have a successful Id4/Azure AD SSO implementation within our ASP.NET WebForms that uses OWIN.

Using the following workflow...

1. User is signed in to CRM or admin.microsoft.com, or any other MS app.
2. User then comes to our app and selects to authenticate using their "Microsoft" credentials, so they click the related icon and are automatically logged in since they are already logged into CRM or other MS app.
3. User signs out of CRM or other MS app, during this log out process from the MS apps, there is a screen on our fs.domain.com page that states they are "logged out of all applications".
4. When they make a subsequent request in our app that requires a ping back to /connect/authorize Id4 still see them as authenticated and they are still authenticated and have not been logged out.

Is Id4 doing any sort of validation to ensure that the these types of authenticated users are still successfully signed into Azure AD?

I would think that if they have logged out of their ADFS that we'd want to expire them in our app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server supports the scenario you are describing. Most likely federated signout is not handled correctly in your situation. Did you register your Identity Server as an app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and did you set the logout URL?

Are you really using Microsoft accounts or AAD accounts? Or is AAD configured to use Microsoft accounts as well?

Comment: Yes we registered our Id server as an app on apps.dev.microsoft.com; yes we set the lot out URL. Our specific AAD is configured to use MS accounts within our on premise ADFS server.

Comment: Are you able to trace the AAD sign out process (after the user has signed in to your IDP via AAD) in browser dev tools and see if a request is made to your registered front channel logout endpoint? If it is then I'd be checking that your logout handler (UserInteraction.LogoutUrl) is behaving correctly. On a related note, once you have front channel logout working if you want your client apps to react immediately then you can  implement the session monitoring spec there and get notified client side if the IDP session changes.